# HTML: Disable number input but the up and down arrow should work

Tags: html, angular

I have this input type number but I need to disable user input on the box. The up and down arrow should increase or decrease the number displayed.

```
<td data-th="Quantity">
    <input type="number" min="1" max="99" class="form-control text-center" value="{{cartItem.quantity}}" formControlName="quantity" #itemQuantity>
</td>
```

[image]

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable all related user keyboard/mouse events like as `onKeyPress="return false"`, `onCut="return false"`, `onPaste="return false"` as following code:

```css
.form-control {
  padding: 8px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 4px;
}

.text-center { text-align: center; }
```

```html
<input type="number" min="1" max="99" class="form-control text-center" value="{{cartItem.quantity}}" formControlName="quantity" #itemQuantity
onkeypress="return false" 
ondragStart="return false" onselectstart="return false"       
oncut="return false" oncopy="return false" onpaste="return false" 
ondrag="return false" ondrop="return false" 
autocomplete="off"
>
```

Comment: please also note that other answers does not keep user from copy-pasting values to input box

Answer (score 3):

```
<td data-th="Quantity">
    <input type="number" min="1" max="99" class="form-control text-center" value=" 
   {{cartItem.quantity}}" formControlName="quantity" (keypress)="eventHandler($event)"  
    #itemQuantity>
</td>

eventHandler(event){
   event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Would you mind adding a brief explanation about what this does and why it works, so that this answer is useful for "newbies", too?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible by using Jquery

```js
$("[type='number']").keypress(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type = "number" value="3" />
```

Comment: why to use jquery if you can use angular2 at your HTML?

Answer (score 1):

try to use (keypress)="eventHandler()"

```
<td data-th="Quantity">
    <input type="number" min="1" max="99" class="form-control text-center" value="{{cartItem.quantity}}" formControlName="quantity" (keypress)="eventHandler($event)"  #itemQuantity>
</td>

eventHandler(event){
   event.stopPropagation();
}
```